# Copy all records with 2 equals data from table1 to one record in table2

Tags: mysql

Good morning,
i have this problem in mysql.
I have a table like this one:

Table1

```
AccessDate__UserCode__AnalisisName____AnalisisResult

2012-01-01____1____________a1______________10  
2012-01-01____1____________a2______________15  
2012-01-01____1____________a3______________12  

2014-03-01____1____________a1______________12  
2014-03-01____1____________a3______________13  

2012-01-01____2____________a1______________14  
2012-01-01____2____________a2______________15  
2012-01-01____2____________a3______________20  

2013-03-01____2____________a1______________3  

2012-01-01____3____________a1______________2  
2012-01-01____3____________a2______________1  

2014-01-01____3____________a1______________10
```

I would like copy the data in an other table setting all the records with same AccessDate and UserCode on the same record, and using AnalisisName value as column pointer.
I mean:

Table2

```
AccessDate___UserCode___a1__a2__a3  

2012-01-01_____1________10__15_12  
2014-03-01_____1________12___-_13  
2012-01-01_____2________14__15_20  
2013-03-01_____2_________3___-_-  
2012-01-01_____3_________2___1_-  
2014-01-01_____3________10___-_-
```

Thank you very much for your help!!
Best regards
Paolo

Comment: How many `AnalisisName` you can have per `UserCode` ?

Comment: i have 20 AnalisisName per UserCode and the table1 has 2500000 records

Comment: i would like to know if it is possible prepare a single query which make this data conversion because table1 has 2500000 records. I wrote also a php script which make this, but it is too slow...

Comment: Hi, someone has some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create new table:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable
(AccessDate date NOT NULL,
UserCode integer NOT NULL,
a1 integer,
a2 integer,
a3 integer,
CONSTRAINT newtable_pk PRIMARY KEY (AccessDate)
);
```

Insert a1 records:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
(AccessDate, UserCode, a1)
SELECT AccessDate, UserCode, AnalisisResult
FROM table1
WHERE AnalisisName='a1';
```

Insert a2 records:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
(AccessDate, UserCode, a2)
SELECT AccessDate, UserCode, AnalisisResult
FROM table1
WHERE AnalisisName='a2';
```

Insert a3 records:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
(AccessDate, UserCode, a3)
SELECT AccessDate, UserCode, AnalisisResult
FROM table1
WHERE AnalisisName='a3';
```

Comment: hi KaiserM11, thanks for the reply!  the problem is that table1 has 2500000 records so i would like launching a single query which execute automatically all the queries you wrote